# after upload my laravel project on free 000webhsot, user part is working but admin part give this error 1-> "View [admin\includes\app] not found "

Tags: php, web, laravel-5, server, laravel-5.4

i try to develop a simple blog with laravel, everything is okay on localhost but when i upload this project on 000webhsot (as a free hot) then user part properly work but in admin part, when i login in admin part i get this error.

View [admin\includes\app] not found. (View: /storage/ssd1/425/7737425/blog/resources/views/admin/home.blade.php)

[error view ][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF62K.png .

this is "view\admin\includes\app.blade.php" code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @include('admin.includes.head')
</head>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">
        @include('admin.includes.header')
        @include('admin.includes.sidebar')


        @section('main-content')
            @show

        @include('admin.includes.footer')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

and this is "resources/views/admin/home.blade.php" code

```
@extends('admin\includes\app')

@section('main-content')

<div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
          <h1>
            Blank page
            <small>it all starts here</small>
          </h1>
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
            <li class="active">Blank page</li>
          </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

          <!-- Default box -->
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Title</h3>

              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        title="Collapse">
                  <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                  <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
              Start creating your amazing application!
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer">
              Footer
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-footer-->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->

        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
      </div>
@endsection
```

---

and the "web.php" code is here

```
<?php

// route for user part //
Route::group(['namespace'=>'user'],function(){

    Route::get('/','homeController@index' );
    //post routes
    Route::get('/post/{slug}','postController@post');
    //tag routes
    Route::get('/post/tags', 'homeController@tags');
    //category routes
    Route::get('/post/category/{category}', 'homeController@category')->name('category');


});
// route for user part end //



// route for admin part //

Route::group(['namespace'=>'admin'],function(){

    Route::get('/admin/home','homeController@home')->name('admin.home');
    //user routes
    Route::resource('/admin/user','userController');
    //post routes
    Route::resource('/admin/post','postController');
    //tags routes
    Route::resource('/admin/tags','tagsController');
    //category routes
    Route::resource('/admin/category','categoryController');

    //Admin auth Routes
    Route::get('admin-login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('admin-login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
});
// route for admin part end//

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending a view that doesn't exist:

```
@extends('admin\includes\app')
```

With dot-notation it should work.

```
@extends('admin.includes.app')
```